# Whats the difference between virsh destroy and virsh undefine

Tags: command-line, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am new to servers and vms wanted to know the difference between

```
virsh destroy
```

and

```
virsh undefine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s take a look into [`man virsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/virsh.1.html):

> ```
> destroy domain
>   Immediately terminate the domain domain.  This doesn't give the domain
>   OS any chance to react, and it's the equivalent of ripping the power cord
>   out on a physical machine. In most cases you will want to use
>   the shutdown command instead.  However, this does not delete any
>   storage volumes used by the guest, and if the domain is persistent, it
>   can be restarted later.
>
>
> undefine domain
>   Undefine a domain. If the domain is running,
>   this converts it to a transient domain, without stopping it. 
>   If the domain is inactive, the domain configuration is removed.
> ```

This indicates that `destroy` is a way to shutdown a domain quite ungracefully, while `undefine` just converts it to a transient one or removes its configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Is there any command that deletes a vm and removes the configuration file in a single go..

Comment: @DheerajChelaramani If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites. If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.